flask db init command executing without end
I had ran the command initially at the start of my project. I accidentally ran it again at the end when I was trying to get the whole project to run.
I tried to remove the migration directory and start again fresh, but the issue was not resolved. I know it worked the first time so I assume the env variables are all properly set.I get no error statements, nothing, just endless execution

Sounds like a lock
